# Meaning of the { } -> "operator" in C++

Tags: c++, syntax, requirements

My activities in C++ have been dormant for a while, so maybe my question isn't appropriate.

I have seen in the definition of concepts a 'strange' syntax like e.g.: `{x + 1} -> std::same_as<int>;`

Is there a name for the `{ } ->` "operator", resp. when has it been introduced into the standard and for what purpose?
I understand its meaning in the context of defining requirements but would appreciate some further information.

Comment: This is not an operator, and it only works inside of `requires`. The documentation for `requires` explains this syntax.

Comment: It means that the type deduced by the expression "x+1" should evaluate to an int. It is used in concepts to constrain input types

Comment: For future questions, please include some context about the code you're wondering about. While it seems like it was easy to guess what it might mean, that's not always the case. If possible, please show a [mre], or at least copy-paste more surrounding code.

Comment: More info here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints

Comment: yeah, out of context `{} ->` can be a part of some expression featuring initializer-list and  access operator `->`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Meaning of the `{ } ->` "operator" in C++

It is not a single operator but what is called a [compound requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/requires#Compound_requirements) and has the form:

> ```
> { expression } noexcept(optional) return-type-requirement (optional) ;    
>
> return-type-requirement   -   -> type-constraint
> ```
>
> and **asserts properties of the named expression.** Substitution and semantic constraint checking proceeds in the following order:
>
> 1. Template arguments (if any) are substituted into expression;
> 2. If noexcept is used, expression must not be potentially throwing;
> 3. If return-type-requirement is present, then:
>    a) Template arguments are substituted into the return-type-requirement;
>    b) `decltype((expression))` **must satisfy the constraint imposed by the type-constraint**. Otherwise, the enclosing requires-expression is false.

(emphasis mine)

This means that `decltype((x+1))` must satisfy the constraint imposed by `std::same_as<int>` which essentially means that the type deduced by/for the expression `x+1` should evaluate to an `int`.

Comment: That answer made my day!